Manually triggered workflow not publishing result
I have these requirements:

main branch must have merge protection (Require status checks to pass before merging) based on the status check associated with GitHub Actions workflow XYZ
when I open a PR workflow XYZ must be triggered (but not when that PR gets synchronized, or any other event)
workflow XYZ also must be manually triggerable (workflow_dispatch)

I have set up the workflow in this way
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened]
  workflow_dispatch:

and just after opening the PR things are fine.
The problem is that when I push a second/third/fourth commit to the PR and then start the workflow manually, even if the workflow is successful:

the result seems to be not available to the PR (thus preventing merging):

I was able to find this related question Github Actions - Workflow job not setting status check, but unfortunately the final solution does not suit my need, because I don't want to run the workflow on PR event other than opened.

If you remove the types line, the workflow is going to trigger when you push a commit into that workflow, which sounds like what you want. I think manually triggered workflows don't know when they're supposed to be associated with a PR.

I cannot remove the types line because otherwise we would get the workflow to run at events other than opened (e.g. synchronized) and that's something I don't want.

But it sounds like you do want to run it when you push new commits?

Or what's the reasoning behind "on open, and then only manually"? I instinctively would want to get rid of the manual step.

The point is our CI is very long and we want to decrease overall executions (for costs reduction). If we don't prevent execution for synchronized event, we have often this situation: PR opening (1 exec), push commit "Changes after review" (1 exec), push commit "Changes after review (2/3/...)" (1+ exec), push for rebasing (1 exec), push for squashing (1 exec). Conversely, if I just leave the execution on PR opening it acts as an initial baseline, then other commits can follow without triggering the CI and as soon as all conversations are resolved the author can manually trigger the final run.
